# Clear history of SSL redirects

Tags: firefox, web-development

I am building a website, and I was debugging the code which redirects between HTTP and HTTPS versions of a page. I found that the HTTP page was always redirecting to the HTTPS page, even when I told it not to. After much tearing out of hair, I found that no redirect was actually being issued. Instead, Firefox had cached the redirect, and was redirecting itself.

This is in spite of the fact that all redirects were temporary `302 Found`. At no point was a permanent redirect ever issued. Clearing the Firefox cache didn't help either. Opera and the [Web-Sniffer](http://web-sniffer.net/) show no redirects, while Firefox continues to redirect.

Clearing the cache usually clears all permanent redirects. Does Firefox have some special behaviour for HTTP > HTTPS redirects, whereby it remembers them even when the cache is cleared? I do not have the HTTPS Everywhere extension enabled.

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
```

Enabled Extensions: All-in-One Sidebar, British English Dictionary, ColorZilla, Dummy Lipsum, Execute JS, Firebug, Link Alert, Live HTTP headers, MeasureIt, RSS Icon, ShowIP, SQLite Manager, Web Developer. I don't imagine any of them will have this effect.

Is this a Firefox bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I have this same issue with Chrome, although it does happen with Firefox too. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Nope. I continued testing in Safari instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem. It seems to be a deliberately coded behavior that if firefox ever connects to the https version of a site it will never again connect via http.

Clearing history and cache have never solved the problem for me, but if you completely blow away the firefox settings (rm -rf .mozilla on Linux) it will again allow you to access the http version of the site. So, it is stored *somewhere* in the firefox settings.

It happens to me with absolutely no redirect headers from the website, no strict transport security headers and with absolutely no firefox addons.

I have seen a lot of people post this behavior as a bug against Firefox. I have not yet seen any reaction other than disbelief. It is hard to get a bug fixed when the developers are in denial. Best thing I can suggest to you is to completely remove all firefox settings when this happens. As for end-users, I guess you just tell them not to use firefox.